# How to add dimmed background to a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uipopoverbackgroundview

I am making custom popover by subclassing UIPopoverBackgroundView (using this [tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/customizing-the-design-of-uipopovercontroller)) and presenting it by using UIPopoverController. Unfortunately as soon as I specify custom popoverBackgroundViewClass the native dimmed background disappears. Is there any way to leave the dimmed background when using custom UIPopoverBackgroundView? Any other solution that I can use to simulate native behaviour?

Comment: Please write your code here

Comment: I updated my question. I added the link to the tutorial that I am using.

Comment: Don’t get it, why to down vote the question?? It is not about how to subclass UIPopoverBackgroundView or why it is not working. The question is: Is it possible to set dimmed background out of the box, if you subclass UIPopoverBackgroundView.

Comment: I didn't down vote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why this got down voted, it's a good question because when you implement a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView, the dimmed background doesn't get set. In researching this problem, I determined the best approach is to set it myself!

Just before creating the popover view, I create a "mask view" that will be added to the view before the popover. This code includes a nice fade in effect as well:

```
self.customPopoverMaskView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    self.customPopoverMaskView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.customPopoverMaskView.alpha = 0.3f;

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:0.3
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^ {
                        [self.view addSubview:self.customPopoverMaskView];
                    }
                    completion:nil];
```

And to remove the view, plug this into the method(s) that handle the popover view disappearing:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:0.3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^ {
                    [self.customPopoverMaskView removeFromSuperview];
                }
                completion:nil];
```

Works well for me. Happy coding!

Aaron

Answer (score 5):

All you need is add next code into initWithFrame: method of your implementation of UIPopoverBackgroundView.

```
UIView *dimView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 - self.frame.origin.x,
                                                           0 - self.frame.origin.y,
                                                           [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,
                                                           [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
dimView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
dimView.alpha = 0.15;
dimView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[self addSubview:dimView];
```

It works as same as default Apple implementation.