# UIPopoverPresentationController dimming background darker

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, uipopovercontroller

I want darker background dim color for `UIPopover`. I know this can be achieved by subclassing `UIPopoverBackgroundView` as mentioned  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167466/how-to-add-dimmed-background-to-a-custom-uipopoverbackgroundview) but I am looking for any simpler way to do this.

P.S. **I am using Objective C not Swift**.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Swift 4**

I just came upon the same problem and found a solution similar to jimmyjudas.

In the viewController displayed as a popover:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.presentingViewController?.view.alpha = 0.3
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.presentingViewController?.view.alpha = 1
    }
```

Comment: Very cool and simple answer. I like it. It would be better with view animation: UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.presentingViewController?.view.alpha = 0.5
        })

Comment: This works great to add extra dimming to a `UISheetPresentationController` too. I also added the animation as @mazend mentioned

Comment: @Trevor,mazend Very short and clean code! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Easiest method is to simply call `self.view.alpha = 0.2` before presenting the popover and setting it back to 1.0 when the popover is dismissed.

Comment: Just to add a few more pointers to this answer, I overrode the ViewWillAppear and ViewWillDisappear in the UIViewController being displayed as the popover to set the alpha on the main view controller's view. (In Xamarin, I used `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.Alpha = 0.5f` with a few checks for nulls along the way.)

Answer (score 3):

Since the user is asking for an Obj C solution - use in the VC that's being displayed in the popover

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.popoverPresentationController.containerView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

UIPopover doesn't background property because it subclass of NSObject 
don't have customizing view property
so you can change its content color -

```
 UIPopoverController *popC = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:TestingPC];
[[[popC contentViewController]  view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackcolor]];
```